# Looping through a dataframe and add values to a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I'm trying to loop through a `dataframe`. All the columns are numeric. I want to get the sum of each column and add it to a dictionary that has the name of the column as the key and the sum of the column as the value.

Comment: Sounds fine. What's your question?

Comment: What library are you using to storing your dataframe?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE: Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help:)